# What type of probabilistic assumption do we make in a MRF if we break a clique by pairwise potentials?

Tags: conditional-probability, graphical-model, markov-random-field

If we have a fully connected MRF with three random variables $a, b, c$, what probablistic assumption would we make if we break the joint potential of the three by pairwise potentials?
$$
\phi(a,b,c) = \phi(a,b)\phi(b,c)\phi(a,c).
$$